# 行ごとに異なるインデックスに” １ ”を持つ numpy 配列を作成するには

Tags: python, numpy

タイトルのような配列を作成したいのですが、効率の良いプログラムが思い浮かばないので
質問させてください。
作成したい配列は、例えば0行目は 0, 2, 4 列目、1行目は 1, 3, 4 列目成分に"1"を持ちそれ以外は"0"を持つといった配列をpythonのfor文を用いずに作成したいです。例で上げた行列は、

```
array = [[1,0,1,0,1],
         [0,1,0,1,1]]
```

といった行列です。各行でどの列成分に"1"を配置するかを指定する行×1の個数のサイズ
（上の例で言えば 2×3 の行列）はすでにあるものとして、効率よく配列を作成する方法があれば
教えていただきたいです。
for文を使った場合のコードは以下のようになりました。

```
import numpy as np
list_1_index = np.array[[0,2,4],[1,3,4]]
array_0_1 = np.zeros(2*5).reshape(2,5)
for i in range(len(list_1_index)):
    array_0_1[i,list_1_index[i,:]] = 1
```

Comment: numpy.newaxis で reshape してみるのはどうでしょうか。`array_0_1[np.arange(array_0_1.shape[0])[:, np.newaxis], list_1_index] = 1`

Comment: 教えて頂いたコードで実現できました。ありがとうございます。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

forループを使わないのであれば

```
array_0_1 = np.zeros([2,5])
array_0_1[[[0],[1]], list_1_index] = 1
```

でどうでしょうか。

`[[0],[1]]` の部分も生成するようにする場合は

```
import numpy as np
list_1_index = np.array([[0,2,4],[1,3,4]])
N,M = list_1_index.shape[0],list_1_index.max()+1
array_0_1 = np.zeros([N,M])
array_0_1[np.arange(N).reshape(N,1), list_1_index] = 1
```

となりますかね。

> ループに比べてそんなにコードサイズ減ってない気がするけど・・

Comment: 参考にさせていただきました。コード自体はコメントを下さった metropolis さんの
コードで実現できました。コードサイズより実行時間を短縮したく、 numpy 内の
iterator でループを回したかったのですが、問題を解決することができました。
ありがとうございます。